# Passing Strongly Typed View Model to Controller as Paramter via Ajax

Tags: c#, json, ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have looked at like twenty answers on here regrading this and none of them seem to be working for me. They all seem hackish as well.

I have this huge View model that I am trying to pass back and forth between two `PartialViewResults` via Ajax. However, nothing seems to work.

Here is a "generic" version of my code:

**Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult _View1(Model model)
{
  return PatialView(model);
}

*I have another one of these for Partial view2*
```

**View**

```
<div id="div1">Load View 1 here</div>

<script>
var m = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    console.log(m);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("_View1")',
        data: {'model' : m},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#View1").html(result);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            $("#View1").html("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Error: Getting View.</div>");
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have tried various configurations on my ajax calls. Any help would be awesome thank you. **I do not want to have to store each variable of the view model into vars and pass them individually to the controller. The view model is way too big for this.**

*Note: When i do a console.log(m) the console of my browser shows me all of my view data. I am just unsure how to pass all of that data to the controller

Note2: If there is a solution that is on stackoverflow already, please feel free to link to it. For some reason i wasn't able to find it.*

Comment: `var m = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` will be the original model, not anything you have edited, so using that would be pointless. And in any case it needs to be `data: m,`

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there a way to post back the newly inputed data that is bound to the model? Thank you for letting me know that `var m = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` Is the original model.

Comment: `var m = $(yourForm).serialize();` (and `data: m,`). But your controller method just shows that your returning the same model back again (which would be crazy) so its not clear what your really doing

Comment: I am having a really hard time following your question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Are you saying that I should serialize the model in a form? Thank you.

Comment: If your editing properties of your view, then yes, But its not clear what your really doing here.

Comment: So I have two `partial views`, each one is bound to the same instance of a view model. However, based upon user preference depends on which view I show. This can be done by a toggle button during presentation of either views on one page. So yes a user can modify parameters in the View model and if they decided to switch to the other partial view i need to persist the data they entered in earlier.

Comment: @StephenMuecke So i have serialized the form via `var m = $('myfrom').serialize();` but I am not sure what the paramter should be on the controller side

Comment: The same as the model in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var m = $('#Form').serialize();   
 $.post( "@Url.Action("_View1")", m)
            .done(function( data ) {
                console.log('done default');
                $("#View1").html(data);
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log('Done')
                    });
```

The problem I was running into was that my view model had two binding for a method via a hidden input. This was causing serialization issues. 
But serializing the form and passing it as the Model Object back to the controller worked.

Answer (score 0):

As data type of the parameter is an object you should pass it to your controller as JSON format. Your ajax options should be like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("_View1")',
    contentType: "application/json", //tell ajax the data you send is JSON format
    data: JSON.stringify(m),
    success: function (result) {
        $("#View1").html(result);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        $("#View1").html("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Error: Getting View.</div>");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have tried this. It gives me a 404. Not found. Any advice?

Comment: It means the destination of server doesn't exists, please check your url. You can try @Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName").

Comment: Justin, I know 404 means not found, I think it is because of the data being passed back to the controller. Do i need to modify my controller at all? I have tried both ways with `@Url.Action`. Still gives me a 404 in the console.

Comment: The way I solve this 404 issue that I make sure the URL is correct or compiled. Otherwise, you can try "/ControllerName/ActionName" instead of rendering from HTML Helper.

Comment: I noticed that i had `data: ` wrong.. so i changed it to what you suggested. That didn't work, i also tried `data: JSON.stringify(@Model)`. This says object Model (as in the object type of my model) is undefined.

Comment: Ok, i took out the `@Url.Action` it is now giving me an error 500

Comment: 500. It means that the URL is correct but the parameter is undefined. @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(object)) will convert your ViewModel to js object and stringify it. You may try data: JSON.stringify("@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(object))")